# Is there some option to require luajit lib to lua5.2 or some simple solution to build torch for lua5.2 on windows

Tags: windows, lua, torch

I am integrating torch with rnn to my project for reinforcement learning on Windows platform. On linux I have not any problem with that. I use in my project lua 5.2 so first of all I want to ask if I can luajit lib include to lua5.2 by require call for example. Or is there any option to build in simple way the torch with rnn in lua5.2 for Windows.

Comment: Why do you need Lua 5.2 on Torch?  The usual choice is: either LuaJIT (fast, but limited to 5.1 functionality) or vanilla Lua 5.2 (slow, but has new features).  Usually the "right choice" for Torch is LuaJIT (as speed is more important).  What Lua 5.2 features you are missing in LuaJIT?

Comment: Because I wrote some simple game engine in C which was integrate lua5.2. And migrate to luajit I think it will be time expensive. And now I have not so much time (master thesis). For that I am finding the most simple and fast solution.

Comment: I get some idea now. I can run from C luajit for torch and also lua5.2 and in C I will create some funcionality for communicating between those instances.

Comment: Why don't you just compile LuaJIT with Lua 5.2 extensions? http://luajit.org/extensions.html#lua52